# ORA-27100: shared memory realm already exists oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to start our db after performing a `shutdown abort` on a oracle 10g server, but atm i'm getting the following message:

> ORA-27100: shared memory realm already exists
>   Linux Error: 17: File

Oracle 10g running under Centos 6.x

Anyone know any leads about solving that issue? I found [this link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_27100_shared_memory_realm_already_exists.htm) but since i dont have a extensive background on oracle db administration i rather confirm if should i follow that instructions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That link seems to be about a problem that's specific to Windows. Why was it necessary to abort the instance? Are there any remaining processes that look like they're related to the instance - if you only have one instance on the server, any processes owned by the Oracle account? Are there any remaining remote connections? You might want to look at the `sysresv` tool but I haven't used that in anger...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your environment before startup.
oraenv is the right tool for that.

```
# oracle user
. oraenv (don't forget the dot)
--> input the SID (if you don't know, cat /etc/oratab)
sqlplus / as sysdba
startup force --performs a shutdown abort + startup
```

Bjarte

Comment: Show us your steps to startup including the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a server restart. Not the correct way to do it ( i supose ) but worked.